# How can I calculate the difference between to dates in a form? The dates (day,Month,year) are in 3 different Drop-down boxes

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, visual-web-developer

How can I calculate the difference between to dates in a form? The dates (day,Month,year) are in 3 different Drop-down boxes. So is it some how possible to get the value of the selected Drop-down which we define in the option tag?

Comment: Can you post some code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var dateA = new Date($("#yearA").val(), $("#monthA").val(), $("#dayA").val());
var dateB = new Date($("#yearB").val(), $("#monthB").val(), $("#dayB").val());
var diff = Math.abs(dateA - dateB);
```

Which will give you the difference between the two dates in milliseconds.

Comment: But the problem is how can I get the values from the drop down list? Specially for the month since it is characters (January, February.. etc.)

Comment: Your select can have separate values & text:
<select id="monthA">
<option value="0">January</option>
<option value="1">February</option>
...
<option value="11">December</option>
</select>
Javascript months are zero-based.

Comment: So Is it also possible to calculate the difference of the separate values defined for each <option> tag and show it in a text box?

Comment: Yes, that would just be a matter of: `$("#monthA").val() - $("#monthB").val()`, given the HTML above. Then repeat the process for the year/day values.